# Can relative flatness of a sheaf be tested using (faithfully) flat morphisms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Given a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $S$, two $S$-schemes $X$ and $Y$ that are flat over $S$ and a coherent sheaf of $O_Y$-modules $F$.

Assume we have a (faithfully) flat $S$-morphism $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ and we know that $\pi^{*}F$ is a coherent sheaf of $O_X$-modules that is flat over $S$.

Can we conclude that $F$ is flat over $S$?

Can we drop the faithfully? Or is this wrong in this generality, do we need to assume more, to get such a result?

My situation is the follwing $X=A\times S$, $Y=B\times S$, for two smooth projective schemes $A$ and $B$ and $F$ is of the form $\pi_{*}G$ for a coherent sheaf $G$ on $X$ flat over $S$, with the property $\pi^{*}\pi_{*}G\cong G$

Comment: No, you cannot drop the "faithfully." For example, if $X$ is the empty scheme, it is flat, but it detects nothing. The empty scheme is a good heuristic for testing whether faithfulness is relevant. In fact, given the characterization of faithfully flat morphisms among flat morphisms as the surjective ones (ie, the ones with non*empty* fibers), it is the whole story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assume less: $\pi$ faithfully flat, $F$ quasi-coherent, no assumptions on structure morphisms. Write down the functors and see immediately their how faithfulness and exactness depend on each other's.

If you need a reference, EGA IV$_2$ 2.2.11 (iii).